# Unable to run python script from shell but able to run it from eclipse(PyDev)

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, centos, pydev

Python version:2.7 OS: CentOS

I have a python project with multiple files spread across different directories. I am able to run this through Eclipse(PyDev). However I am unable to run it from linux shell.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
      Projectrepo
          |
          |
        __|__
    src       conf
     |          |
     |          |
 buildexec.py   |
                |
             script_variables, list_of_scripts
```

`buildexec.py` is my main script. `script_variables` and `list_of_scripts` are two modules which I am referencing from buildexec.py.

I have included `from conf.script_variables import *` in my main script and it is working fine when I run it on eclipse. But, when I try to run it on shell, I get an error

`'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "buildexec.py", line 6, in <module>
    from conf.script_variables import *
ImportError: No module named conf.script_variables'`

I have added PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python2.7 and have exported it..

Also, in the main script, I have added

`sys.path.append('/home/tejas/Projectrepo/conf')` before importing the modules.

Comment: Why did you add `/home/tejas/Projectrepo/conf` instead of `/home/tejas/Projectrepo` to sys.path?

Comment: you have the __init__.py files in those directories?

Comment: Added it since the modules I wanted to reference are under `conf` directory. However, I tried only `/home/tejas/Projectrepo` also but was not able to run.

Comment: yup, have __init__.py files in both directories.

Comment: @Tejas what if you replace that `append` with `sys.path.insert(0, '/home/tejas/Projectrepo')`?

Comment: i hope you added sys.path.append before the imports right?

Comment: Hello, I tried adding `sys.path.insert(0, '/home/tejas/Projectrepo')` and still unable to run on shell.

Comment: Yup, have added it before the imports!

Answer (score 0):

Was a simple solution! My pythonpath was pointing to the default directory /usr/bin/python2.7. I added the location of the user defined modules also in the python path using                                                            `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python2.7:/home/tejas/Projectrepo/conf`

Comment: But, the thing is it works when I manually set it on the terminal. Since I will be sharing my script with others, is there any way I can set the PYTHONPATH from the script itself? I tried `sys.path.append(["/usr/bin/python2.7:/home/tejas/Projectrepo/conf/"])`  in the script but it still does not set it.